# How to get perspective right in illustrator cs4?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective, cs4

I have been enjoying designing in illustrator a lot but while designing a home for landscape i found it difficult to get precise perspective for 'Home'.

So the question is how to get perspective to look precise /right in illustrator cs4(below cs5 version). CS5 has got perspective grid but i don't have one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason you *need* the perspective grid feature to create perspective in Illustrator. People were drawing perspective designs for over a decade before that feature was added.

Simply create your own grid by drawing a series of lines all related to appropriate vanishing points, then use the `View > Guides > Make Guides` menu item to turn them into guides.

[image: guides]

Answer (score 0):

Other than upgrading to CS5, I would suggest drawing out your own grid on paper, then scan it in as a jpg or any file extension you prefer, then place that grid on its own layer and lock it. Then setup another layer to digital recreate it and once you have drawn back over the original on another layer, lock the new grid layer and then proceed with your project that way. That is how I would approach it, would recommend trying this out but being a designer takes years of practice and trial and error. Hope this helps.